can I overwrite the malloc called by library functions?
my code (main.c):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* __real_malloc(size_t size);
void __real_free(void* ptr);

void* __wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = __real_malloc(size);
    printf("custom malloc size=%ld ptr=%p\n", size, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void __wrap_free(void* ptr)
{
    printf("custom free ptr=%p\n", ptr);
    __real_free(ptr);
}

// gcc -o mybin main.c -Wl,--wrap=malloc -Wl,--wrap=free
int main() {

    const char *original = "Hello, World!";
    char *copy;

    copy = strdup(original);
    printf("Original: %s\n", original);
    printf("Copy: %s\n", copy);

    void *ptr = malloc(100);

    free(ptr);
    free(copy);

    return 0;
}

my output:
Original: Hello, World!
Copy: Hello, World!
custom malloc size=100 ptr=0x55a845ef06d0
custom free ptr=0x55a845ef06d0
custom free ptr=0x55a845ef02a0

man page says strdup calls malloc. why don't I see two 'custom malloc' calls in the output?
when I call malloc, it's the custom one. when strdup calls it, it's the standard one. why ?
env: simple x86 VM running Ubuntu

Perhaps strdup doesn't actually call malloc, but some other memory allocation function? Or (more likely) perhaps it's in a library that is already fully linked, so your linking process can't do anything about it?

man page says memory is obtained with malloc. I am free-ing the memory after strdup, I ran with gcc address sanitizer and didn't report anyhting.

@CatalinDemergian From the ld man page(see --wrap=symbol): "Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".  Any undefined reference to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol".  So only undefined references to malloc will be fixed up by the linker to point to your __wrap_malloc implementation.  It's possible (indeed probable) that due to the way libc is built all internal references to malloc etc. are already resolved -- so your __wrap_malloc will never be considered in those cases.

ltrace may tell you something interesting.

Small nitpick: size_t printf format is %zu

Also - never call printf() from within a custom malloc() or free() implementation.  printf() and a lot of other similar functions can and will call malloc() themselves and you'll get infinite recursion.  Try adding more than just "...size=%ld ptr=%p\n", size, ptr ) to your printf() call and see what happens.

Linker can wrap only in functions that are being compiled. You are calling printf, which is defined in libc, which linker can't change.
Ususally custom mallocs are loaded with LD_PRELOAD.
